# Number format for a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes, pgfplotstable

In the following minimum working example, how do I change number format that is used for the node? For instance, cut off the number after 5 digits.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
    640     9     9 1.111111111111111e-01 1.111111111111111e-01 1.234567890000000e+00 3.360958503340160e-03 6.801367190507313e-04 6.801883693667268e-04 1.234567890000000e+00 1.234567890000000e+00
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot coordinates{(0,0) (1,1)};
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]{7}}\of{data.txt};\edef\nodeText{\pgfplotsretval};

            % HOW DO I CHANGE THE NUMBER FORMAT FOR THE NODE HERE?
            \draw[draw opacity=0] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:1,1) node[pos=0.5] {\nodeText};
            % HOW DO I CHANGE THE NUMBER FORMAT FOR THE NODE HERE?

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the `pgfplots` manual, changing the number format is described for ticks (4.13 Number Formatting Options, Revision 1.12 (2015/01/31)) but not for nodes. How should I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enclose `\nodeText` within the same tags you find in that chapter. Here for example I used `\pgfmathprintnumber[sci]{...}`. But you can change it to the format you prefer.<sup>1</sup>

A note: the author of `pgfplots` advised not to use `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}`, because if it gets updated and there are changes, it will affect your code. Better stick to a defined version so the result is the same regardless of the updates.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
    640     9     9 1.111111111111111e-01 1.111111111111111e-01 1.234567890000000e+00 3.360958503340160e-03 6.801367190507313e-04 6.801883693667268e-04 1.234567890000000e+00 1.234567890000000e+00
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot coordinates{(0,0) (1,1)};
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]{7}}\of{data.txt};\edef\nodeText{\pgfplotsretval};
            \draw[draw opacity=0] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:1,1) node[pos=0.5] {\pgfmathprintnumber[sci]{\nodeText}};

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

<sup>**1:** [Pgfplots manual, version 1.12.1](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf), chapter 4.13 - Number formatting options, page 265.</sup>